# Specify routes in Middleman

Tags: ruby, routes, config, middleman

Is there a way to specify routes in middleman?

Specifically, would it be possible to have simple pages like about, contact, etc. be in their own folder, e.g. static/about, and render to the root when you build the site?

Answer (score 2):

Middleman treats the `source` folder as its root. For instance, the index.html page in the `source` folder will show up on the host's root (if you're testing on localhost, http://localhost:4567/).

To add a route to `/`, all you need to do is create another file— `contact.html.erb`, say— in the `source` folder. Once you have some HTML, navigate to http://localhost:4567/contact.html, and your new page should be served up.

If you want your routes to work without the .html extension, you can add this line to your config.rb:
`activate :directory_indexes  #Removes .html from file`